# Someone requested my resume, what should I include in the thank you letter?

Tags: resume, communication, job-search, new-job, non-profit

I am a social worker trying to move into the for-profit industry. I have a second job as a cashier at a well known retail store.

A customer and I were having a conversation as I rang her up. I told her I have a full time job as a social worker she gave me some suggestions on places to apply for a job. I told her I wanted to move into corporate. She handed me her card and told me to send her my resume.

She works for talent acquisition company. I want to forward my resume to her but I am not sure what to include in the accompanying thank you letter. Do I need to include a cover letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar thing happen once. I wrote a full cover letter, referencing the earlier conversation I'd had with the recipient, then going into some of my skills relating to potential positions. Also put in something about how I was really interested in joining the organization in some useful capacity, and hoped to hear from her when something opened up.

When I sent my CV and cover letter, my e-mail was very brief, just generally referencing our conversation (not as much detail as in the letter, where I went into a bit more of the events surrounding the conversation), reiterating my interest in possibly joining her team, and my pleasure at meeting her. I handled it like another job I was applying for, just noting details relating to our conversation, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this may work better for me because I can mention skills that are not included in my resume.

Answer (score 11):

Don't think "thank-you letter" so much as "first formal contact".  You want to remind her of who you are (because she probably talks to dozens of people every day) and acknowledge her request.  Something like:

> Thank you for talking with me yesterday at $location about positions in social work.  (A sentence or two about your background, like you would in a cover letter.)  As you requested, I'm sending you my resume.  I look forward to hearing from you about positions that would be a good fit.
>
> Thank you.
>   (signature)

As you do more networking you'll have conversations like this all the time and you'll develop a "pitch" for this email (and, for that matter, for your verbal introduction).

Comment: Thank you, so much! You really helped lower my stress level.

Comment: +1 for "remind her". This is very important. I've gotten stuff from people weeks after an interaction and it almost looks unsolicited. You want to remind her of that warm feeling she had.